# JavaScript not changing HTML Styles

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the color of my name, by clicking on a button. Here is what I've done till now,

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<p id="demo">Sandeep Roy</p> 
<button type="button" onclick="change()">Click</button>
<script>
function change() {
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.style.color=red;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected output is a red font, when 'click' button is clicked.

Unfortunately nothing happens when I do that, i.e same black color font. 
Please help me educating in this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the below, you're missing quotas

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.style.color=red;
```

should be

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.style.color='red';
```

besides that - this approach is awful. Toggling classes is more preffered.

Comment: Thanks for educating & your time. Please help with a good book for JavaScript for a beginner.

Comment: Try this one: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do - It think it's the best for start.

Comment: Thanks again Sir, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

In this case `red` is variable. You should use string instead. Use

```
x.style.color='red';
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntax mistake

```
x.style.color='red';
```

Answer (score 2):

**Correct -** red color assign as a string name or value(hex color code like '#ff0000') of the color.

```
Syntax- object.style.color="color|initial|inherit"

x.style.color='red';
x.style.color='#ff0000';
```

You can see the live demo on [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/HimanshuSharma/3oemmho3/3/)

```html
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<p id="demo">Sandeep Roy</p> 
<button type="button" onclick="change()">Click</button>
<script>
function change() {
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
x.style.color='red';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for educating.

Answer (score 1):

Missing quote at the line below.

```
x.style.color='red';
```

Comment: Thanks you for you time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works,

```html
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<p id="demo">Sandeep Roy</p> 
<button type="button" onclick="change()">Click</button>
<script>
function change() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Himanshu Sharma assign id value in variable and changed it's style but i try to change without variable name.

Comment: this approach seems more compact, i don't have to assign variables, then follow other the procedures. Now simply i can directly assign the changes i want to do. Thanks for educating. I really appreciate.